# Reclustering in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a snowflake and need to apply clustering to table for every run of application. If clustering information is changed it would change the cluster keys and it will also trigger reclustering, but what happens when the clustering information is not changed meaning if columns are same as the current cluster keys then we add the cluster keys using alter statement, would it still recluster?

Eg

consider tableA, I added cluster key using alter table tableA cluster by (name)

Now after some time, I reapply this, the same query will it result in reclustering?

Comment: Hi - I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but you define clustering on a column (or columns) in a table not on the values in those columns. So once you've defined the clustering on a table Snowflake will automatically cluster the data as you load it - you don't need to do anything. You would only change the clustering if you wanted to cluster on different columns - and you'd have a pretty unusual design/dataset if that's something you needed to do regularly

Answer (score 4):

@Manish you seem to be confused about cluster keys.  Let's assume you have a fact table where most of the queries look like this...

```
select ...
from big_table
where date_id between <Date Start> and <Date End>;
```

You might consider altering the table and creating a CLUSTER_KEY using:

```
alter table big_table 
cluster by date_id;
```

In background, the automatic clustering service will cluster your table by DATE_ID.

There is not need to apply the cluster key again.

You need to be careful however.  Keep in mind the following advice from Snowflake:

1. Only consider cluster keys on tables at 1TB or more
2. Only cluster if you find the PARTITIONS_SCANNED is close to the PARTITIONS_TOTAL.  IE. You currently don't partition eliminate and this leads to poor query response times.
3. Ensure the cluster key appears as a predicate in the WHERE clause of queries.
4. Be wary of placing cluster keys on tables where a significant proportion of the partitions are frequently updated.  This may lead to a high cost of reclustering as updates can disrupt the clustering sequence.

Check the existing clustering on the table using:

```
select system$clustering_information('big_table');
```

If the results you get look like this - your table is VERY well clustered:

```js
select system$clustering_information('ORDERS_BY_DAY', '(O_ORDERDATE)');
{
"cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(O_ORDERDATE)",
"total_partition_count" : 6648,
"total_constant_partition_count" : 6648,
"average_overlaps" : 0.0,
"average_depth" : 1.0,
"partition_depth_histogram" : {
"00000" : 0,
"00001" : 6648,
"00002" : 0,
"00003" : 0,
"00004" : 0,
"00005" : 0,
"00006" : 0,
"00007" : 0,
"00008" : 0,
"00009" : 0,
"00010" : 0,
"00011" : 0,
"00012" : 0,
"00013" : 0,
"00014" : 0,
"00015" : 0,
"00016" : 0
}
}
```

If however your table looks like this, it is BADLY clustered, and you should consider creating a cluster key.

```
select system$clustering_information('snowflake_sample_data.tpcds_sf100tcl.web_sales','ws_web_page_sk');

{
"cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(ws_web_page_sk)",
"total_partition_count" : 300112,
"total_constant_partition_count" : 0,
"average_overlaps" : 300111.0,
"average_depth" : 300112.0,
"partition_depth_histogram" : {
"00000" : 0,
"00001" : 0,
"00002" : 0,
"00003" : 0,
"00004" : 0,
"00005" : 0,
"00006" : 0,
"00007" : 0,
"00008" : 0,
"00009" : 0,
"00010" : 0,
"00011" : 0,
"00012" : 0,
"00013" : 0,
"00014" : 0,
"00015" : 0,
"00016" : 0,
"524288" : 300112
}
}
```

The key indicator you need to look for is the

"average_depth"

This shows the average number of partitions a query will scan for a lookup on a given value.

For example:

```
select ...
from big_table
where date_id = to_date('22-May-2022','DD-Mon-YYYY');
```

If you executed the above and it returned:

```
"average_depth" : 300112.0
```

This indicates on average the above query will need 300,000 partitions read to find the values.  If however it says:

```
"average_depth" : 10
```

This indicates less than 10 partition reads.  Which on a large table (with over 300,000 partitions), is VERY Well clustered.

Provided your "average_depth" is 10 or under, you're fine.  However, keep in mind, we're assuming that most queries are limited by DATE_ID.

In conclusion.  If you think you've identified a valid case for a cluster key, it should be created once and then costs monitored.

You should also check your query performance is improved on queries which hit the table and filter by the cluster key - in this case DATE_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question.

So to rephrase, you mean to say there is a table A with a clustering key on the column "name". Now you add another clustering key say on the column "class".

If my above understanding is correct, Definitely, it will recluster. Think of this data is stored in micro partitions and arranged based on the clustering key. If another clustering key is added, it will have to sort/re-arrange the data again in micro-partitions based on the clustering keys.

Comment: what happens when we try to apply cluster key on column for which there is already a cluster key;

suppose I added cluster key on column name using alter;

now after sometime if I do the same 

alter table tableA cluster by (name); 

What will happen in this case

Comment: A table can only have one cluster definition. Your ALTER statement is not adding a column to the cluster definition If, it is redefining the cluster definition in its entirety. If you change that definition then the table will get re-clustered.

Comment: yes @NickW is right.